# Translation Api text to text and text to speech for IOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, translation

- **Hello, I am trying to find some 3rd party sdk or api services for
  translation, I have  found speechtrans, but they don't offer trail period so
  can'test it, I have used gast library for it but its output is not
  precised, so please guide me or suggest me any services or sdk
  through which i can translate.**

Comment: AVSpeechSynthesizer using to convert the text to speech. visit the Link to third party Api for translation:http://www.raywenderlich.com/1448/google-translate-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-translate-text-with-google-translate-and-json-on-the-iphone

Comment: Hari, this is google, library, and gast is also a affiliated with google. so please suggest something else. google translation is not precised.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/getstarted.aspx